# How to extract all specific values from a string in a row in pandas dataframe with regex?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have specific values in a string in a Dataframe row, which is a complete mess. These are reviews scores scraped in the following format:

```
 data = {'split': ['5,   60% 4,   20% 3,   7% 2,   5% 1,   7% 4.2 out of 5']}
 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would need this format, meaning that I have to split above long string into these columns and corresponding values. Each rating (1-5) should have corresponding % assigned.

```
 data = {'5': ['60%'], '4': ['20%'],  '3': ['7%'],  '2': ['5%'], '1': ['7%'], 'rating': [4.2]}
 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I was thinking about `df['split'].str.extract(pat = '(\d+%)')` to extract all the numbers with % at first, but doesn't really work. It extracts only first number with %, not all from the string. Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't really work"? With `data = {'split': ['5',  '60% 4',  '20% 3', '7% 2', '5% 1', '7% 4.2 out of 5']}` and then `df['split'].str.extract(pat = '(\d+%)')` it seems to work. `data['split']` is wrong for sure, since it is fetching you a string, and not a Series (so it has no `.str` attribute).

Comment: Olu, am I right that you see "*AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'*" error message?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I corrected question to make it more clear :), thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'split': ['5,   60% 4,   20% 3,   7% 2,   5% 1,   7% 4.2 out of 5', '15,   20% 4,   40% 3,   5% 2,   2% 1,   37% 3.2 out of 5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_out = df['split'].str.extractall(r'(\d+%)')[0].unstack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
df_out['rating'] = df['split'].str.extract(r'(\d*\.?\d+)\s+out\s+of\b', expand=False)
```

Output:

```
>>> df_out
match    0    1   2   3    4 rating
0      60%  20%  7%  5%   7%    4.2
1      20%  40%  5%  2%  37%    3.2
```

Notes:

- `df['split'].str.extractall(r'(\d+%)')[0].unstack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)` extracts all `\d+%` matches and puts the results into a dataframe with unstacked values and reset index
- `df['split'].str.extract(r'(\d*\.?\d+)\s+out\s+of\b', expand=False)` extracts the int or float number before an `out of` substring.